# Take certain value in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've just started the python. I want to ask a question. I have a dataset as follows:

```
Value
120/100
130/90
123/101
```

I want to take after than "/". Example for;

```
Value
100
90
101
```

Thank you for helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and pick the last element using `str[-1]`:

```
In [232]: df.Value = df.Value.str.split('/').str[-1]

In [233]: df
Out[233]: 
  Value
0   100
1    90
2   101
```

Comment: Additional information.  If there are more than 1 `'/'` and definitely want the last one, this is a tad more efficient: `df.Value.rsplit('/', 1).str[-1]`  This limits the split to split only once and starts from the right hand side.

Comment: @Gego feel free to upvote this answer in addition to checking it as the chosen answer (if in fact, you do).

Comment: @piRSquared I'm very new in this platform. If i doing wrong something, im sorry. Thank you for helps.

Comment: @Gego no worries.  That's why I said something.  Whenever someone answers your question satisfactorily and is helpful, give it an upvote to show your appreciation.  You can upvote more than one answer.  If there are one or more satisfactory answers, make sure to choose one of them as the chosen answer.  Choose the answer by clicking the checkmark.  Also, you don't have to choose the first answer posted.  IMO, choose the best one.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Ok.